# How do I display a MovieClip in FlashBuilder?

Tags: flash-builder

I'd like to know how to display in Flash Builder an external movieclip (.swf) stored in an assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `swfloader` to load swf files to a application ,

```
<s:SWFLoader id="loader"source="@Embed('assets/mymovieclip.swf')"/>
```